# What is the Google Cloud Platform's "Managed Infrastructure Mixer Client"?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Can someone tell me what the purpose of the “Managed Infrastructure Mixer Client”? I have it showing up on my GCE logs and I can’t find any information on it. It is adding and removing GCE instances.

I believe it is related to GCP's recommended settings:

```
Automatic restart - On (recommended)
On host maintenance - Migrate VM instance (recommended)
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, have you found out more info about this? I'm seeing mass restarts of my VMs with this agent in my logs, and I'd also like to know more about the reason for this.

Comment: Same here. I had 3 servers in an MIG (different zones) and they all got restarted within a span of 30 secs, leaving no time to auto-heal. Ideally they should be restart per zone (or zone-wise)

Answer (score 0):

This is the User Agent used by [Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups_and_autohealing) when performing operations on instances. These operations can result from both user operating on the MIG (e.g. resizing, recreating instances), as well as operations performed by Autoscaler, Autohealer, Updater, etc.

Note that this string may change in the future.